# How to make Xamarin Studio in OS X stop draining my storage space while running on virtual machine?

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, virtual-machine, xamarin-studio, vmdk

I have setup Vmware workstation on my Windows PC to run MAC OS in it. I am using Mac on a windows machine for xamarin.ios development. Mac OS is of 7.4 GB , XCode is 12 GB and Xamarin studio is of 1 GB in size in Mac os. I use Xamarin mac agent from visual studio (windows machine OS) to connect to Mac (running on virtual machine) over the internet, but during this testing phase, my Mac OS is getting bigger and bigger in size. The problem is, It’s .vmdk file Is getting larger in size and taking much space on my windows hard drive. I have not installed anything in it but when Mac gets connected to internet, it’s eats memory. Can anybody help me how do i get my lost Storage space back?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: each time you build something on macOS, is creating a package (Archives) which will contain all the binaries necessary to make your app run. This is a terrible issue as a Developer I have found using macOS.

Keep this in mind because each time you build an IPA to test or deploy (either to an iPhone or to Apple Store) it will create a cache of this (also archives which are pretty large).

Please, read this article that may help you to keep your mac virtual machine in tune:

[Can I add files to or remove files from an IPA file after building it in Visual Studio?](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/modify-ipa/)

Also, I recommend you to put a fixed size to you vmdk image to stop increasing it into your pc.

Hope this help you.

Best regards.